# How do I clean an app of dead carrierwave entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

In my app, there are numerous entries with a carrierwave uploader, where the uploaded files have disappeared. I want to remedy this in a *rake* task, but I am unable to set these uploaders to **nil** or remove them. A typical session follows:

```
[43] pry(main)> article
=> #<Product id: 80, name: "Barcelona", ambient_picture: "ambient.jpg", special: false, slug: "barcelona", image: "image.jpg">
[44] pry(main)> article.remove_ambient_picture!
=> nil
[45] pry(main)> article
=> #<Product id: 80, name: "Barcelona", special: false, slug: "barcelona", image: "image.jpg">
[46] pry(main)> article.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

and so on ad nauseam—nothing seems to help. The referring remove method seems more like a hub to other callbacks, so it is possible that this only works if the file is actually exists.

So what should I to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for now I resorted to this:

```
    unless article.ambient_picture?
      p "Removing #{article.ambient_picture}"
      sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
      sql.update "UPDATE articles SET ambient_picture=null WHERE id=#{article.id}"
    end
```

I know this is not ideal, so just out of curiosity, I'd still welcome a suggestion, how this could be handled in a saner way.